# Source appx files for inbuilt Windows apps

Tags: group-policy, deployment, windows-10, application

I am trying to configure the following GPO object for a Windows 10 machine, on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Application Control Policies > AppLocker > Packaged app rules

I need to add the following exceptions:

1. Microsoft.Getstarted
2. Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub
3. Microsoft.SkypeApp
4. Microsoft.WindowsFeedback

On the Exception configuration screen, I have 2 options

1. Use an installed package app as a reference
2. Use a packaged app installer as a reference

I don't really want to have to install consumer applications on my server in order to be able to configure group policy.

My preference would be to just point my server to the appx files for the aforementioned applications.

So the question is, where can I get the appx files for the above applications.

I have tried the installation locations on a Windows 10 PC and also I tried extracting the install.wim from the Windows 10 source files, both to no avail.

There was also some mention on the web of using Fiddler to grab the source file URL when downloading it from the Windows Store, but that didn't work for me either.

Or do I need to configure the Group Policy from a remote Windows 10 machine and point to the locally installed applications?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this other site:
https://www.vmadmin.co.uk/microsoft/43-winserver2008/352-applocker
Same instructions  but he has you first installing Microsoft program called Remote Server Administration Tools on the Windows 10 machine. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520
This allows you to update the server GPO from the windows 10 machine that has the apps. Worked for me.